# Where can I get Ubuntu Stickers

Tags: laptop

Where can I get Ubuntu inside or Powered by Ubuntu or any Ubuntu sticker for that matter to stick on my Laptops?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

System76 offers free Ubuntu stickers, which you can check with your local Ubuntu community through https://system76.com/swag/stickers

Comment: the link is dead

Comment: alive for me, but no Ubuntu stuff there!

Answer (score 2):

Editor's note: [the shop has closed down](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2019/05/canonical-shop-ubuntu-closed) so this answer is no longer useful

---

Have a look at the below link

[Ubuntu Stickers](http://shop.canonical.com/product_info.php?products_id=718)

Answer (score 1):

Another good source for Ubuntu and Linux merchandise in general is [unixstuff](http://www.unixstuff.net).

From the [page description](http://www.unixstuff.net/index.php?page=about):

> **ABOUT UNIXSTUFF**
>
> This community project is brought to you by Richard Weber to help
>   showcase your pride-and-joy. Linux is a Unix-like computer operating
>   system assembled under the model of free and open source software
>   development and distribution. Like many other Linux projects around
>   the world, we make no profit on this. We promote Linux in many
>   countries and we hope to build a Community around UnixStuff.

Answer (score -2):

Editor's note: the shop is now closed

---

You can purchase Ubuntu stickers and wearables in the dedicated Ubuntu site: http://shop.ubuntu.com/